# Change Aurora Serverless engine version/family in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Where can I change the Aurora Serverless engine version/family through the AWS web console?
If I click Modify on the database page I don't see any setting (but that's where it is for non-Serverless databases), nor do I see a setting in Parameter Groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you **can't change it directly**. For the aurora serverless you can [only modify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.modifying.html):

- Minimum Aurora capacity unit
- Maximum Aurora capacity unit
- Timeout action
- Pause after inactivity

If you want to change version of Aurora Serverless (for example from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7), you can **snapshot** your Aurora Serverless DB, and the **restore** to new Serverless MySQL to new version. This will allow you to change MySQL version, but not from MySQL to PostgreSQL. For that probably need to use [AWS DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/).

Comment: @tschumann Updating this in CFN, would probably result in deletion of your existing DB and creation of a new one.  But it would not migrate data out of the box. For this you need snashott first. You can try on some dummy db for tests. Nevertheless, you question was about AWS console, not CloudFormation.